# Should I grease pins when re-installing them on cottered cranks?

Tags: maintenance, crankset, restoration

I'm restoring a vintage Peugeot with cottered cranks.  When reattaching the cranks to the bottom bracket spindle, should I grease the pins or put them in dry?

Comment: The answer will be along the lines of installing a crankset on a square-taper spindle - to grease or not to grease... I've heard compelling arguments for and against.

Comment: Yes, first get them clean and burr-free (and also make sure the flat is burr-free), then a light coating of oil or grease.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The grease will aid in installation as well as later removal.